# Pandas: query() groupby() mean() using second column list

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to decypher some inherited pandas code and cannot determine what the list *[['DemandRate','DemandRateQtr','AcceptRate']]* is doing in this line of code:

```
plot_data = (my_dataframe.query("quote_date>'2020-02-01'")
                         .groupby(['quote_date'])[['DemandRate', 'DemandRateQtr', 'AcceptRate']]
                         .mean()
                         .reset_index()
            )
```

Can anyone tell me what the list does?

Comment: `mean` will applied on groups from only these columns `[['DemandRate', 'DemandRateQtr', 'AcceptRate']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is filter by columns names, here are aggregate only columns from list.

```
['DemandRate', 'DemandRateQtr', 'AcceptRate']
```

If there are some another columns like this list and from `by` list(here `['quote_date']`) are omitted:

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        'quote_date':pd.date_range('2020-02-01', periods=3).tolist() * 2,
         'DemandRate':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'DemandRateQtr':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'AcceptRate':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'column':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

print(my_dataframe)
  quote_date  DemandRate  DemandRateQtr  AcceptRate  column
0 2020-02-01           4              7           1       5
1 2020-02-02           5              8           3       3
2 2020-02-03           4              9           5       6
3 2020-02-01           5              4           7       9
4 2020-02-02           5              2           1       2
5 2020-02-03           4              3           0       4

plot_data = (my_dataframe.query("quote_date>'2020-02-01'")
                         .groupby(['quote_date'])[['DemandRate', 'DemandRateQtr', 'AcceptRate']]
                         .mean()
                         .reset_index())
print (plot_data)

  #here is not column
  quote_date  DemandRate  DemandRateQtr  AcceptRate
0 2020-02-02         5.0            5.0         2.0
1 2020-02-03         4.0            6.0         2.5
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is it significant/important that the list is using double brackets?  [[   ]]

Comment: @bumblebear - yes, in some oldiest versions no problem, in last pandas version get warning if omit it.

Comment: @bumblebear - `FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.`